# Mismatch in dataframe count operation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created 2 data-frames

Dataframe1 :

1. Read a PostgreSQL DB : Table-A
2. Convert Table-A as parquet file
3. Read parquet file as dataframe

DataFrame2 :

1. Read a PostgreSQL DB : Table-A
2. Convert Table-A in to CSV file
3. Converted CSV file in to parquet file
4. Read the parquet file as dataframe

All these operations are geared towards counting number of records

Commands I have used are

DataFrame1:

```
 df1 = spark.read.jdbc( )
 df1.write.parquet( )
```

DataFrame2 :

```
df = spark.read.jdbc( )
df.write.csv( )
df2=sqlContext.read.parquet(CSVfilePath)
```

When I view count of both dataframe why are they different ? Does Spark handle the conversion operation differently based on the source ?

I noticed the count of CSV and Parquet file is same.

Comment: I'm curious why are you `parquet(CSVfilePath)` which would suggest that you read CVS files as if they were in parquet format? Is that intended?

Comment: As part of requirements we want to maintain CSV and Parquet file of the table so I created a CSV file , and created parquet file using parquet(CSVfilePath)

Comment: You know that you cannot load a CSV dataset using `parquet` method, don't you?

Comment: I was not aware of it . I am very new to Spark framework, so I am still learning. Why can't I load CSV data using parquet method ?

Comment: The same reason you can not play cricket with a football and vice-versa as they are of different format.